# что за json из майл API

Tags: php, json, mail.ru

Господа, извиняюсь за такой вопрос, но реально задолбался, короче получаю из майл  API результаты в json формате, если `print_r($answer)` то на экран получаю;

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [pic_50] => http://avt.appsmail.ru/mail/king_marat/_avatar50
>             [friends_count] => 13
>             [pic_22] => http://avt.appsmail.ru/mail/king_marat/_avatar22
>             [nick] => Bemulima
>             и т.д.
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Но никак не могу пользоваться, пробовал так и так:

> ```
> echo 'мой ник '.$answer->user->nick.'<br/>'; 
>        echo 'мой ник '.$answer->nick.'<br/>'; 
>        echo 'мой ник '.$answer[nick].'<br/>'; 
>        echo 'мой ник '.$answer["nick"].'<br/>';
>        echo 'мой ник '.$answer['nick'].'<br/>'; 
>        echo 'мой ник '.$answer[0][nick].'<br/>';
>        echo 'мой ник '.$answer['0']['nick'].'<br/>';
>        echo 'мой ник '.$answer["0"]["nick"].'<br/>';
> ```

На экране вижу только 'мой ник' и все, а самого ника вижу, есть еще варианты как пользоваться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  echo 'мой ник '.$answer[0]->nick.'<br/>';
```

Comment: Спасибо)не додумался